# How to output a CSV file with fortran(separate with comma) on one line?

Tags: csv, fortran

I'm the beginner of Fortran.

I would like to ask you how to get CSV file.

In my case, I use this code for get output:

[image]

However, Unfortunately, after calculation, I get this result like this:

[image]

I would like to write the value at one line.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Or please tell me another best method how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not use images for your output - cut and paste it into the question

Comment: You need to use a format statement instead of the wild card format `*`, as no information is provided about the types of the variables and required precision no information can be given about the format. Please don't post code snippets but a so called minimal working example showing your problem.

Comment: A CSV-file should not look like something that is formatted because of the use of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Steve's first rule of Fortran - never use list-directed output when you care about the layout.

Fortran has several features that can help you here:

- The `G0.d` format that will accept any intrinsic datatype and format numerics in a form Excel will accept
- The `*` infinite group repeat count that repeats the following format group as many times as is needed by the input data
- The `:` edit descriptor that stops processing non-data-transmitting format elements

Combining these can serve you well in your quest for CSV output. For example:

```
implicit none
real :: x(2),y(2),rou(2)
integer :: i
x = [-1.,-1.0007]
y = [0.,0.]
rou = [-1.499337,-1.499337]

do i=1,2
  write (*,'(*(G0.7,:,","))') x(i),y(i),0.0,rou(i)
end do
end
```

outputs:

```
-1.000000,.000000,.000000,-1.499337
-1.000700,.000000,.000000,-1.499337
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a format statement.  Assuming you want the number formats shown in your image

```
      do i = 1, mx
         do j = 1, my
            write(99, 900) x(i,j), ",", y(i,j), ",", 0.d0, ",", rou(i,j)
         end do
      end do

900   format (F8.4, A, 2(E8.2,A), F8.6)
```

If you want the file to have a header row, write it before the do loop using a different format statement